# Running Consul on Vagrant: Port forwarding from guest to host not working on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vagrant, portforwarding, consul

I would like to setup a Consul Cluster with a UI on my local machine (Mac OS X) using Vagrant.
So far I simply followed the Getting Started instructions of the official Consul Docs: https://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/join.html

In order to be able to access the UI from the host, I simply added this one line to the provided Vagrantfile (https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/demo/vagrant-cluster/Vagrantfile)

```
n1.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8500, host: 8500
```

To start Consul with a UI on the guest machine I ssh into the machine and then simply added the -ui flag to the provided command:

```
consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 \
    -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent-one -bind=172.20.20.10 \
    -enable-script-checks=true -config-dir=/etc/consul.d -ui
```

Consul starts without problems and from with the guest machine I can execute:

```
curl -v 'http://localhost:8500/ui/'
```

and the expected HTML page is returned.

Trying to access `http://localhost:8500/ui/` in a browser or via curl on the host does not work though. Using curl on the host results in:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8500 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8500 (#0)
> GET /ui/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8500
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Anything I am missing with setting up the port forwarding correctly?
The logs after running `vagrant up` look good to me:

```
n1: Forwarding ports...
    n1: 8500 (guest) => 8500 (host) (adapter 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options :

1. Use a static IP (either a [public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html#static-ip) or [private network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html#static-ip)) so you will bind your consul agent on the static IP (say `172.20.20.10`) and you will be able to access through `http://172.20.20.10:8500/ui/` from your web browser

Note : in such case, you dont need to have the forwarded port in your Vagrantfile

2. per [consul doc on bind option](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bind)

> The address that should be bound to for internal cluster communications. This is an IP address that should be reachable by all other nodes in the cluster. By default, this is `"0.0.0.0"`, meaning Consul will bind to all addresses on the local machine

so you will be able to reach consul running on your VM from your host

NB: my preferences goes for option #1

Comment: thanks, you are right. I've already specified an IP in the private network, so there is no need for port forwarding.

What I was missing was also specifying the client IP address to bind to.
(https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_client).
So finally with this command the UI is available from the host on 
`http://172.20.20.10:8500/ui/`.

The command therefore needs to look as follows:
`consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent-one -bind=172.20.20.10 -client=172.20.20.10 -enable-script-checks=true -config-dir=/etc/consul.d -ui`

Comment: Had absolutely the same problem today. Just want to point that the problem is in "-client" argument. In tutorial it's not specified, but consul sets up two different servers for internal and ui usage and you need to bind them separately.

Answer (score 1):

`consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=agent-one -bind=172.20.20.10 -client=172.20.20.10 -enable-script-checks=true -config-dir=/etc/consul.d -ui` is a good solution, but it has side effect that any consul cli operations will return error because it uses `127.0.0.1` in http request. so maybe changing `-client=172.20.20.10` to `-client=0.0.0.0` is better.